# MobileFirst8.0 Sample Cordova Project doesn't run for Windows8.1 App

Tags: windows, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Running with

> cordova run windows

command will start up and go down immediately.
I think that it is caused by

> WLWin8Native.ChecksumPlugin ()

of worklight.js, but I do not know the solution.

please,help me. thank you.

Comment: Which sample application are you trying to run?

Comment: mfpconsole → Get Starter Code →　Download Center　→ Cordova sample application.
thanks for your question.

Comment: How do you know it is checksumplugin() that causes it? What is Cordova version you are using? What is your Cordova-windows version? Did you do a Cordova prepare before you ran the project?

Comment: thanks.

cordova ver 6.5.0 (I tried it even at ver 6.4.0)
windows platform ver 4.4.3 (I tried it even at ver 4.4.2)
I executed "cordova prepare" command.

WLWin8Native.ChecksumPlugin (). CalculateChecksum (""). Done ()  is delayed by 10 seconds with SetTimeout, and after 10 seconds go down.
(in MFPStarterCordova \ platforms \ windows \ platform_www \ plugins \ cordova-plugin-mfp \ ​​worklight \ worklight.js)

Comment: Can you try a lower version of Cordova and 4.4.2 . For example cordova-6.1@4.4.2 ? Check if the issue is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobilefirst Windows SDK packages with architecture specific DLL's. Hence `cordova run windows` command will fail as it runs for `AnyCPU`.

In order to run platform specific commands you need to add `--` separator before `--archs=x64`.

Try with command `cordova run windows -- --archs=x64`, I hope it should resolve the issue.

Comment: I solved it thanks to your answer. thanks!! thanks!!　
And, thanks to everyone else.